# PLSQL Script is waiting for user input

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to run one PL SQL Script but when I run script it is waiting for user input if I press enter then only script will continue and print log.
But in sql file there is no such command to wait for user input
I heard that there are some special chars in PL SQL that waits for user input..
What could be the reason?

Comment: Do you have a `&` somewhere in the SQL script?

Comment: Try adding slash `/` at the end of your script. Provide a sample of script if this doesn't help.

Comment: I have & in comment section will that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Look for `&` in your code which triggers [user's input](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref453).